# Upgrading curl but 'openSUSE-12.3-Update-Non-Oss' appears to be outdated

Tags: opensuse, curl, zypper, php5

My webserver is running a Magento 1.8.1.0 that uses php-curl under the hood. 
It runs openSUSE 12.3 and:

```
PHP 5.3.17
Apache 2.2.29
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.33
OpenSSL 1.0.1j
```

The curl version installed is:

```
curl -V
curl 7.28.1 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.28.1 OpenSSL/1.0.1j zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

I need to upgrade the curl to at least v. 7.34 since my version of curl doesn't support TLSv1.2 for php and PayPal is obliging to use TLSv1.2.

I tried running:

```
zypper update curl
Loading repository data...
Warning: Repository 'Updates for openSUSE 12.3 12.3-1.4' appears to be outdated. Consider using a different mirror or server.
Warning: Repository 'openSUSE-12.3-Update' appears to be outdated. Consider using a different mirror or server.
Warning: Repository 'openSUSE-12.3-Update-Non-Oss' appears to be outdated. Consider using a different mirror or server.
Reading installed packages...
No update candidate for 'curl-7.28.1-4.47.1.x86_64'. The highest available version is already installed.
Resolving package dependencies...
```

It seems that there are no updates available for my openSUSE-12.3 OS.

Since it is a production server what is the best way to upgrade curl on the machine?

Should I add another repository containing the latest version of curl and run zypper update again?

Do you have any suggestion on how to handle this upgrade without breaking anything?

Comment: Compare with
[Why do I get "Warning: Repository 'oss_update' appears to be outdated"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/433240)

Answer (score 2):

The *best* way (maybe not the most simple one) is to upgrade the whole server, not only curl.

openSUSE 12.3 is end-of-life since Jan 29th 2015. This means your *production server* has all security problems which were found since almost 2 years.

Answer (score 1):

Download newest curl package:

```
https://curl.haxx.se/download.html
```

or from git:

```
git clone https://github.com/curl/curl.git
```

and:

```
./configure --with-ssl && make && make install
```